# Problema al mostrar perfil Roundme en Webview Android Studio

Tags: android, webview

Hola amigos buenas tardes, hoy quisiera pedirles por favor que me ayuden a resolver este caso, estoy tratando de mostrar el recorrido fotográfico de la universidad, en la red social de fotografías de 360 grados Roundme, lo he hecho de tres maneras pero unicamente me funciona usando el navegador del dispositivo móvil, en el contenedor WebView simplemente se queda en blanco; nosé si sea posible que esta página "Roundme" no permita poner su contenido en WebView, ya que cuando cambio la url por otra, todo funciona bien.

En el siguiente código el WebView se queda en blanco, no carga contenido, tampoco me genera error.

```
    wv = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wvtour);
    wv.loadUrl("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

En el siguiente código me ocurre lo mismo, muestra el contenido en blanco y tampoco genera error.

```
    String url="https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/";
    wv =(WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.wvtour);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Y con el siguiente código, sí muestra el recorrido fotográfico usando el navegador predeterminado en el dispositivo.

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al realizar el `Intent` y abrir el navegador del dispositivo puedes ver sin problema la página a diferencia de usar el `WebView`, la razón es que **el `WebView` es un navegador limitado que no tiene todas las funciones de Chrome, y no soporta todos los objetos javascript.**

Incluso la página que comentas usa Adobe Flash Player que no es soportado.

La opción en este caso es abrir la url en el navegador externo:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://roundme.com/tour/114616/view/");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por el aporte